# What can cause form inputs to intermittently not be clickable ie not be focusable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a single page site, and am finding that sometimes input form elements aren't working ie they're not clickable. This seems to be intermittent, as they are clickable most of the time, and it's Chrome that it happening in.

To take a look, please login at https://www.songbookdb.com/dashboard with the credentials:

u:testLogin
p:pppppppp

- choose the Your Gigs option from the menu
- click the Add New Gig button
- see if you can click in the input fields

If not, why would that be?

The code of one of the forms that this happens in is here (gigsInfo is one of the fields that's affected):

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="createGigFRM" name="createGigFRM">
                        <h2>Add New Gig:</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="gigsVenueDropDownMenu">
                                <label>Gig venue:</label><br />
                                <small class="gry2">No venues? Go to the Your Venues screen (top right menu) to add one.</small> 
                                <div class="field"><SELECT NAME="gigsVenuesDD" id="gigsVenuesDD" SIZE="1"></SELECT></div>
                                <small id="gigsVenuesDDHelp" class="textError">Please add at least one venue to your venues list (via the Your Venues screen) before adding a gig.</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label>Date of gig (or first gig):</label><br />
                                <input type="text" id="gigDatepicker" name="gigDatepicker" readonly>
                                <small id="gigDatepickerHelp" class="textError">Please select your gig date</small>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>How often gig occurs:</label><br />
                            <div class="field">
                                <SELECT NAME="gigsFrequencyDD" id="gigsFrequencyDD" SIZE="1"><option value="1">weekly</option><option value="2">every 2 weeks</option><option value="3">every 3 weeks</option><option value="4">every 4 weeks</option><option value="M">monthly</option><option value="">one off gig</option>
                                </SELECT>
                                <span id="frequencyLabel"> on a </span><span id="dayLabel"></span>
                            </div>
                            <small id="gigsFrequencyDDHelp" class="textError">Please select your gig's frequency</small>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Time:</label>
                            <div class="field">
                                <SELECT NAME="gigsHoursDD" id="gigsHoursDD" SIZE="1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8" selected="selected">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option>
                                </SELECT>
                                <SELECT NAME="gigsMinsDD" id="gigsMinsDD" SIZE="1"><option value="00">00</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="45">45</option></SELECT>
                                <SELECT NAME="gigsTimePeriodDD" id="gigsTimePeriodDD" SIZE="1"><option value="am">am</option><option value="pm" selected="selected">pm</option></SELECT>
                            </div>
                            <!--<small id="createVenueStreetAddressHelp" class="textError">Must be 1-128 characters long.</small>-->
                        </div>                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Duration in hours:</label>
                            <div class="field">
                                <SELECT NAME="gigsDurationDD" id="gigsDurationDD" SIZE="1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4" selected="selected">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option>
                                </SELECT>
                                <small id="gigsDurationDDHelp" class="textError">Please choose a duration</small>
                            </div>                         
                        </div>                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Rig:</label>
                            <div class="field">
                                <SELECT NAME="gigsRigDD" id="gigsRigDD" SIZE="1"><option value="1">Rig 1</option><option value="2">Rig 2</option><option value="3">Rig 3</option><option value="4">Rig 4</option><option value="5">Rig 5</option><option value="6">Rig 6</option><option value="7">Rig 7</option><option value="8">Rig 8</option>
                                </SELECT>
                                <small id="gigsRigDDHelp" class="textError">Please choose the rig that this gig will be using</small>
                            </div>                         
                        </div>                             
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Info:</label><br />
                            <small class="gry2">Drinks specials etc (leave blank if no info). Urls and other html will be disabled here.</small> 
                            <input id="gigsInfo" type="text" class="formField" name="gigsInfo" placeholder="leave blank if no info">
                        </div>   
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="gigsPayPalEmailsDIV">
                                <label>Tip the DJ PayPal account for this gig: <a href="#" class="helpToolTip" id="tipTheDJPayPal_helpTip" title="This text will display in the tooltip pop-up">?</a></label><br />
                                <div id="tipTheDJPayPalHelpTip" class="helpTip">
                                    <p>Any tips made at this gig (via the 'Tip the DJ' button on the SongbookDB app) will be paid into the PayPal account you select/add here.</p>
                                    <p>You can edit your PayPal account email list via the Tip the DJ PayPal Emails screen</p>
                                    <p><small class="gry2">SongbookDB takes no commision from tips - the full amount minus Paypal fees is credited to the Paypal account set up for that gig, and email notifications are sent to both the recipient and the payer of the tip.</small></p>
                                    <button id="tipTheDJPayPal_close" class="closeHelpTip">OK</button><br />
                                </div>                                                                         
                                <div class="field" style="margin-top:10px;"><SELECT NAME="tipPayPalDD" id="tipPayPalDD" SIZE="1"></SELECT></div>
                                <div class="form-group" id="createPayPalEmailGigScreenDIV">
                                    <p><em>or</em></p>
                                    <label for="createPayPalEmailGigScreen">Add new PayPal email:</label>
                                    <input id="createPayPalEmailGigScreen" type="text" class="formField" name="createPayPalEmailGigScreen" placeholder="leave blank if none">
                                    <small id="createPayPalEmailGigScreenHelp" class="textError">Must be a valid email address 1-128 characters long.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>   <!-- END id="gigsPayPalEmailsDIV" -->
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group no-margin">
                            <button type="submit" id="createGigSUBMIT" name="createGigSUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save Gig</button>
                            <button id="cancelAddNewGigDivBTN">Cancel</button>
                        </div>                                                
                    </form>
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I can click in the input fields.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: Are there any particular browsers for which this is an issue?  (I can also click the input fields, using Chrome.)

Comment: Hi JayC. Chrome seems to be the main one. Thank you.